# How to use button constructor in discord.py?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Discord.py won't ever be updated again, but buttons are still implemented. Thing is, they aren't in the docs. It seems rather intuitive, but for one thing: the constructor for the `Button` class asks only for a "data" parameter of the type `ButtonComponent`. Could someone please explain what this is? Is it like slash commands where it is a type encompassing specific dictionaries? Am I being completely misguided in my thinking that I understand Buttons on discord?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

well, actually the docs for the master branch of [discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#id7) is there, where you can find buttons and the newly implemented things.
also, you can always look up for some demo examples in [github](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tree/master/examples/views).

Comment: Sorry, I was on that same site and I searched and it didn't find Button, but your link worked. Thanks!

Comment: happy to help :)